# Given functionals $q_1,q_2$ and $q_3$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ determine if they form a basis of the dual space.

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have the following linear functionals:
$$q_1(x,y,z)=2x-y+3z$$
$$q_2(x,y,z)=3x-5y+z$$
$$q_3(x,y,z)=4x-7y+z$$
then in order to show that the linear functionals form a basis can I just find the determinant of the matrix 
$$\left[\begin{matrix}
2 & -1 & 3\\
3 & -5 & 1 \\
4 & -7 & 1 
\end{matrix}
\right]$$
of this matrix and show that it is not equal to zero. Will this solution work?

Comment: It is correct. If you need to justify this, you'll need to work a little bit more, though.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha:=\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}=\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ denote the standard basis of $\mathbb R^3$. Then any linear function $f$ from $\def\rt{\mathbb R^3}\rt$ to $\mathbb R$ can be uniquely written as $f(e_1)f_1+f(e_2)f_2+f(e_3)f_3$, where $f_i$ is the function defined as $f_1(x,y,z)=x,\quad f_2(x,y,z)=y,\quad f_3(x,y,z)=z$.
In fact, $\bar\alpha:=\{f_1,f_2,f_3\}$ is the [dual basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_basis) corresponding to $\alpha$.

Then the matrix in question is the matrix representation of the functions $q_i$ with respect to this basis $\bar\alpha$. We know that these three elements form a basis if and only if the matrix of them with respect to another basis is invertible, hence if and only if the matrix under discussion has non-zero determinant.
Therefore your solution works.

---

Hope this clarifies some doubts.